# How to stop GIF loop in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How to stop gif loop after 1 time? It is animating forever.

```
Image(
  color: Colors.red,
  image: new AssetImage(Icn.splash),
  width: 150.0,
),
```

Answer (score 15):

Solution
- Go to https://ezgif.com/loop-count
- Upload gif
- Set loop count 1 (0 - infinity)
- Change loop count and download gif

Comment: Or use convert tool in linux like:
    convert -loop 1 splash.gif splash2.gif

Comment: the gif loop once and won't loop again on second time, how to fix this? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Two steps:

1. Edit the gif loop count from 0(infinite) to 1 using any online gif editing tool like https://onlinegiftools.com/change-gif-loop-count and/or https://ezgif.com/loop-count and download the edited gif. This would ensure that the gif is played only once.
2. Manually evict the image cache to ensure the gif is played again when the user navigates away and/or uses the back button and revisits the page assuming the goal is to play the gif every time the user visits the page but just once.

Sample code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OneTimeGifLoader extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _OneTimeGifLoaderState();
  }
}

class _OneTimeGifLoaderState extends State<OneTimeGifLoader> {
  late AssetImage myAssetImage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myAssetImage = const AssetImage("assets/path/to/my/image.gif");
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    myAssetImage.evict(); //Evict image cache
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("One time gif loader"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: myAssetImage,
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            ),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this flutter package will help;

A flutter plugin to control gif animation: https://pub.dev/packages/gif_ani

Comment: thanks for reply. but this package's latest version is too old.

Answer (score -1):

this code:

```
Image.asset("assets/tasky_logo.gif",
            gaplessPlayback: false, fit: BoxFit.fill)
```

Comment: Not working, Can you please test it again.